# how to find a socket's ip address c++/c

Tags: c++, c, sockets

I want to know how to get the IP address of a client who connects to a socket on a server using accept.  How would I do this? getpeername returns a wrong IP address, and I can't seem to find another way to do it.

On the server, after accept returns, I'm doing this:

```
            char buf[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
            struct sockaddr name; socklen_t len = sizeof(name);
            getpeername(sock_fd, &name, &len); //sock_fd is the socket im using
            inet_ntop(AF_INET, &name, buf, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
            string ip = buf;
```

Comment: Please show us some of your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 2nd parameter of accept has this information.

Comment: +100. To anyone looking for the easiest way to do this, if you have access to the accept call, use the param there. I've had getpeername being really quirky, but this solution has worked much better.

Answer (score 4):

You have several errors:

- You should not create an object of type `struct sockaddr`.  Instead, you should be using `struct sockaddr_in` or `struct sockaddr_in6` depending on the type of the socket;
- You should check the return value of `getpeername()` for errors.
- You must pass a pointer to a `struct in_addr` or `struct in6_addr` to `inet_ntop()`, not a pointer to a sockaddr.

It should look like:

```
char buf[INET_ADDRSTRLEN] = "";
struct sockaddr_in name;
socklen_t len = sizeof(name);

if (getpeername(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&name, &len) != 0) {
    perror("getpeername");
} else {
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &name.sin_addr, buf, sizeof buf);
}
```

You do not need to use `getpeername()`, though - you can instead pass `(struct sockaddr *)&name` and `&len` as the second and third parameters of `accept()` and proceed from there.

Answer (score 2):

Wild guess, based on the limited information currently available: Make sure you're calling `getpeername()` on the accepted connection, not on the listening socket.

When `getpeername()` returns, it's writing to what is probably going to be an `in_addr_t` (or `in6_addr`!) structure. Use a routine like `inet_ntoa` to format and display the result.